Netlify "serverless" functions on front end cannot import ... really anything
I am working on a project that is React front/Node back, but utilizing Netlify's "serverless" functions for deployment there. loginUser.cjs is used for "GET"ting users from the server. It is able to import User.js model from the server-side directory, and bcrypt from npm, to help with validation. This all works.
signupUser.cjs (which is in the same dir as loginUser.cjs) cannot access the User model or bcrypt (or other imports), using what I believe to be the correct paths.
Project tree is...
• root/client/functions (contains netlify functions: n-loginUser.cjs, n-createUser.cjs)
• root/utils/validation.mjs (one import I've been attempting to access)
• root server/models (contain User.js, others)
Error I receive on Netlify is `Cannot find module '/var/task/utils/validation.mjs' (switch in /models/User.js for that import, which also fails).
I have tried duplicating these files in the functions directory and importing from there and get similar errors. I don't understand why 1 file can import, while another in the same directory cannot, when they both have paths leading to the same place.
I have searched stack overflow and other sites and cannot find an answer.
